# can't edit textedit when I command git rebase -i

Tags: git, rebase

I practiced `git rebase -i` in my local.
I use this command.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~7
```

output is here.

```
pick 8631468 add test6.txttor to close the file... 
pick 10c300c test1-1
pick 93ebed2 test1-2
pick 3de0f6c test1-3
pick 44bc475 test1-4
pick 4432c1b test1-5
pick bb194e9 remove stash

# Rebase 97ac5cc..bb194e9 onto 97ac5cc (7 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup <commit> = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec <command> = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# b, break = stop here (continue rebase later with 'git rebase --continue')
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
# l, label <label> = label current HEAD with a name
# t, reset <label> = reset HEAD to a label
# m, merge [-C <commit> | -c <commit>] <label> [# <oneline>]
# .       create a merge commit using the original merge commit's
# .       message (or the oneline, if no original merge commit was
# .       specified). Use -c <commit> to reword the commit message.
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/branch1.
```

I want to edit textedit. but texteditor is forced to finish and rebase is successed. how do i edit text? please help.

Comment: Are you asking for a vi tutorial?  Try setting EDITOR to an editor you know.

Comment: What text editor program would you like to use? Are you on Mac? Good options are TextMate and BBEdit.

Comment: TextEdit is a poor choice, but if you really want to use it, say `git config --global core.editor "open -W -n"`. (Source: https://ericasadun.com/2018/07/12/using-textedit-as-your-git-editor/)

Comment: thank you advice. After registering vim in git config, it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TextEdit by default doesn't make the command line wait for you to close the file before continuing.

You'll need to use `-W` on `open` to make it wait for the application to close. `-n` will open a new instance of the app so that quitting the app doesn't affect other documents you have open.

To use **`open -Wn`** as your Git editor:

```
git config --global core.editor "open -Wn"
```

Then when TextEdit opens, to continue in Terminal, save & close the document and quit TextEdit.